# Check values with tolerance

Tags: java

I am trying to check whether one value equals + or - 2 the other value.

This is what i have come across.

```
    for (int lineNumber : errorLineList) {
        if (lineNumber == startLineNumber
                || lineNumber == (startLineNumber + 1)
                || lineNumber == (startLineNumber + 2)
                || lineNumber == (startLineNumber - 1)
                || lineNumber == (startLineNumber - 2)) {
            lineFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But here if i want the tolerance to be 5, then i have to add 10 checks.

Is there any other elegant way to do this in java.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is often need when using doubles as you can get small rounding errors.

```
if(Math.abs(lineNumber - startLineNumber) <= 2)
```

You can change 2 to 5. This is says; if the difference between two values is less than 2. i.e it could be -2, -1, 0, 1 or 2.

For `double` a similar solution is to test "equality" using

```
if(Math.abs(a - b) < ERR) // where ERR is 1e-4 or 1e-9
```

What is a good value of ERR to use depends on the situation.

Comment: true, with abs() that is even better, +1

Comment: This is what i was looking for, +1 ,Thanks. Couldn't understand your double solution.

Comment: @UnniKris - In the double sample, Peter uses [epsilon comparison](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) because floating point numbers are not exact.

Comment: 1e-4 is 0.0001 and 1e-9 is 0.000000001

Answer (score 6):

You are interested in the value difference. You don't care what value is higher, you are just interested in they difference. That we can obtain by `lineNumber - startLineNumber`. That is nice, but it produces positive as well as negative values. So when we you absolute value of this difference we have their distance which can be used for comparison.

```
if ( Math.abs( lineNumber - startLineNumber ) <= 10 ) {
   // values are in tolerance -10 .. +10, ... 21 values
   // the range of tolerance in now simple changeable by one number 
   //            .. the distance of values, which can be defined 
   //            as a constant wherever you want, 
   //            static final field, property file, ..
}
```

Comment: That will give a range of 21 possible values.

Answer (score 1):

of course:

```
int tolerance = 5; //or any other value you want...
for (int lineNumber : errorLineList) {
    if(lineNumber <= (startLineNumber + tolerance) &&
       lineNumber >= (startLineNumber - tolerance)){
        lineFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: that was good than what i have written, +1, but i like the abs implementation better..

Comment: yes, the abs solution is shorter & cleaner. more elegant. i like it too. thanks for up-vote :)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
if (lineNumber >= (startLineNumber - 2) && lineNumber <= (startLineNumber + 2))
```