# Java modulus equivalence with Scanner and Files

Tags: java, file, modulus

So, I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or what but essentially I have a file with integers like (1 2 3 4 5 6) etc. I'm reading in this file with the Scanner class and then wish to determine if they are actually integers using File.nextDouble() % 1. Which should result in 0.0 if it is an integer.

Heres the basic code:

```
public static void range(Scanner inputF){
    double hold = 0.0;

    while (inputF.hasNextInt()) {
        hold = inputF.nextDouble();
        if(hold % 1 != 0.0){
            System.out.println("Invalid");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

And what is happening is the "if" statement is catching even though 1 % 1 = 0;

Thanks!

Comment: *wish to determine if they are actually integers using File.nextDouble()* - `hasNextInt()` already checks for integers.

Comment: Maybe you should add a print statement after your `nextDouble` for debugging. When I run this with a file having 1-6, I do not go in the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

For double data types such as the variable `hold` - do not use comparison operators such as `==` or `!=`. For the reason why see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383975/check-values-with-tolerance) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207577/when-comparing-floats-what-do-you-call-the-threshold-of-difference).

You can do something like below -

```
double tolerance = 0.00000001d;
double mod = hold % 1;
if(mod <= tolerance) {
    ...//Do your operations.
}
```